# SFDX CLI - Locked with an active writer?

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

I'm getting the following error when trying to access the sfdx command :

[image]

Does any one know what's happening ?
I can't find anything here nor on the internet..

I tried re-installing the CLI + rebooting my PC, but it still persists.

EDIT : I tried sfdx update -->

[image]

Comment: Looks like an update operation failed or got stuck and didn't remove its lock file. If you manually delete `update.lock` in the directory shown, does the issue resolve?

Comment: I'll try and edit this comment, I edited my post with a screenshot of "sfdx update" test !
Thanks ;)

Comment: Well ! It seems to work, thanks ;)
Quick and efficient !

Comment: @AlexisMASSON You should mark David's answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it, working on my project : just did it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes processes fail unexpectedly and leave behind lock files. In most cases you should be able to manually remove the file by navigating to your local `AppData` folder (the file will live elsewhere on other operating systems) and deleting it from your file manager.

Sounds like you've been able to resolve this issue just by removing `update.lock`.